# Getting the output of a process

Tags: elisp

I am trying to create a function which takes as input a path and returns the output of the `ls` terminal command as a string. I'm using a process and sentinel since I'll eventually want to create other functions which will take some time to execute, and I want them to run asynchronously.

```
(defun ls-to-string (path)
  (let (ls-proc
    ls-output)
    (progn (setq ls-proc (start-process "" "ls-buffer" "ls" path))
       (set-process-sentinel ls-proc (lambda (p e)
                       (if (string= e "finished\n")
                           (progn (set-buffer "ls-buffer")
                              (setq ls-output (buffer-string))
                              (kill-buffer "ls-buffer")
                              (message ls-output)))))   <---- (1)
        ls-output)))   <---- (2)

(ls-to-string "/home")
```

I have (temporarily) added `(message ls-output)` just to show that ls-output does contain the string (1). However the return value is nil (2).

Comment: Why not use [`shell-command-to-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html) instead?

Comment: Isn't `shell-command-to-string` synchronous? I plan on constructing other functions which may take minutes to execute, and I don't want emacs to hang during that time.

Comment: OK. The fundamental problem with your code is that `(message ls-output)` runs in the context of the sentinel, but the return from `ls-to-string` is in the context of the call to `ls-to-string`; the sentinel might not have been invoked yet by the time `ls-to-string` returns, in which case `ls-output` will be nil. It's hard to know how to answer your question without knowing more about what you're doing with the output of the commands.

Comment: "I don't want emacs to hang during that time", but you were expecting your `ls-to-string` to hang until the process had finished, in order that `ls-output` had been set.  i.e. You were assuming synchronous behaviour.  For asynchronous processes, it's your *sentinel* function which must take the next step.  It's the only thing which can act on the result of the process.  i.e. `start-process` and `set-process-sentinel` have both completed before the process has completed, and Emacs then carries on with arbitrary other activity, until such time as the process ends and your sentinel is invoked.